# Why the result is always appear on the 1st row?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm exporting data from SQLite into `.csv` but I got problem on rows why the result is always  appear in the 1st row? did I miss something??

RESULT:

[image]

My Code:

```
private void DataExport()
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog
            {
                Title = "Choose file to save to",
                FileName = ".csv",
                Filter = "CSV (*.csv)|*.csv",
                FilterIndex = 0,
                InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
            };


            if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
                String sSQL;

                sSQL = "select * from Tile1";
                cmd.CommandText = sSQL;
                clsCon.con.Open();
                cmd.Connection = clsCon.con;
                SQLiteDataReader dr2;
                dr2 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dr2.Read();

                DataSet _dataSet = new DataSet();
                DataTable _dataTable = new DataTable();

                for (var i = 0; i < dr2.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    _dataTable.Columns.Add("" + dr2.GetName(i) + "", typeof(string));
                    _dataTable.Rows.Add("" + dr2.GetValue(i) + "");
                }

                var rows = _dataTable.Rows;

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                IEnumerable<string> columnNames = _dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(column => column.ColumnName);
                sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

                foreach (DataRow row in rows)
                {
                    IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
                    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
                }

                File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog.FileName, sb.ToString());

                clsCon.con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you mean by "why the result is always appear in the 1st row". Please give more details.

Comment: I mean the result for rows is continuously go down in the 1st row instead of each column has it.

Comment: Well you've shown the result as an Excel table when you're actually just writing it to a text file, which doesn't help us much. What does the text file look like? (And please tell us what diagnostics you've performed. Have you stepped through in a debugger, for example?)

Comment: be more specific about question....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try simplifying your code a bit, I mean those DataTables and DataSets are driving me nuts:

```
private void DataExport()
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog
    {
        Title = "Choose file to save to",
        FileName = ".csv",
        Filter = "CSV (*.csv)|*.csv",
        FilterIndex = 0,
        InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
    };

    if (!saveFileDialog.ShowDialog())
    {
        return;
    }

    using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Tile1";
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog.FileName))
        {
            var columnNames = Enumerable
                .Range(0, reader.FieldCount)
                .Select(reader.GetName);
            string header = string.Join(", ", columnNames);
            writer.WriteLine(header);
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var values = Enumerable
                    .Range(0, reader.FieldCount)
                    .Select(reader.GetValue);
                string valuesRow = string.Join(", ", values);
                writer.WriteLine(valuesRow);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks the DataTable object has not been filled correctly, check the part here:

```
   for (var i = 0; i < dr2.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        _dataTable.Columns.Add("" + dr2.GetName(i) + "", typeof(string));
        _dataTable.Rows.Add("" + dr2.GetValue(i) + "");
    }
```

I guess you tried to set up columns of the data table here, but you can't append rows in the same time, you actually add each column values of the first row into different rows. The table you generated would be like this:

```
      col1        col2      col3       col4
row1  val(1,1)
row2  val(1,2)
row3  val(1,3)
row4  val(1,4)
```

val(x,y) means value at column y and row x in database.

@Darin Dimitrov 's solution works very well for your issue.